# Understanding Threads in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm quite new to the concepts of threads in JAVA and though I tried a couple of codes and they are working I really don't exactly understand whats happening in the background. For example I wrote this piece of code:

```
public class myThreadTest implements Runnable {
  private static void ping(String text, int count) 
                      throws InterruptedException {
    for (int i = 0; i<count; i++) {
      System.out.println("ping "+text+i+"...");
      Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
  }
  public void run() {
    try {
      ping("run ",10);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
  }  
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    (new Thread(new myThreadTest())).start();
    try {
      ping("main ", 5);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
 }
}
```

are there 2 threads being executed here one running from main and the other from the method run? Bcoz the output I get is main,run,main,run,run,main... something like that.

Answer (score 3):

Yes ,the both  executing concurrently.

> *A thread is a thread of execution in a program. 
>   The Java Virtual Machine allows an application to have multiple threads of execution running concurrently.*

I am highly recommending [this docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) before starts coding .good luck

Answer (score 2):

That's correct. Try printing the [thread id](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getId%28%29) in your `ping()` method to see that different threads are running (you can also name your threads and I follow that as a practise so I can understand which thread is doing what)

Answer (score 2):

Threads in java have mainly to do with concurrency, which is s the notion of multiple things happening at the same time.A thread is an independent path of execution within a program.

From your program I can see your code is starting two threads at start up running the first command the for loop sleeping for 1 second then and then running run method and back and forth until the for loop is exhausted so the run continues to 9

Answer (score 0):

There are two threads. One of the threads is created and starts executing its `run` method asynchronously due to the `start` call in the main block. The other thread is executing the `main` method itself.